# Convert Json to two possible objects

Tags: c#, json

I am currently receiving two different types of objects in Json format and I need to deserialize those Json into corresponding objects. However, my problem is that all of those objects are sent by the same channel which means when I receive an object but I don't know which type the object is. The two different types of objects is shown below. So my question is if there is a function that allows me to try to deserialize with one object type and if that fails, I use another one?

```
//Object1
public class OutputStream
{
    public DateTime summaryId { get; set; }

    public string total { get; set; }

    public int userId { get; set; }

    public string dataType { get; set; }

    public SensorLocation location { get; set; }

    public HeartRateActivityType activityType { get; set; }
}

//Object2
public class OutputStreamAMM
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime summaryId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string average { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string max { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string min { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int userId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string dataType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SensorLocation location { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public HeartRateActivityType activityType { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which library are you using for deserialization? Where is your code for it? Sample jsons for each one?

Comment: Hard ways that will always work: (1) Peek the stream, check if you see either `total` or `average/min/max` fields, then deserialize either as first or second class. or (2) define a 'union' object that has **all** fields of both classes, deserialize as it, then inspect and translate them into objects of different classes depending on criteria from point 1, or (3) deserialize as expando/dynamc/idictionary etc then inspect and translate as in (2)

Comment: I am using Json.NET and the currently I only know that we need to use the code like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> (object) to ddeserialize the object. But I really want to know if there some function which takes two possible object types and decide which one to use at runtime.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Regarding (3), I would recommend deserializing into a `JToken` (see my answer) instead of a dynamic object. You could even safely check the presence of a deeply nested property like `token.SelectToken("fieldA.fieldB.fieldC") == null`, whereas `dynamicObj.fieldA.fieldB.fieldC` could cause a `RuntimeBinderException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a [Json Schema](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) for one of your models, and then validate your json document against the schema to see if it matches.

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this.

```
var schema = JsonSchema.Parse(...);
var jtoken = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

if(jtoken.IsValid(schema))
{
    var model = jtoken.ToObject<OutputStream>();
}
else
{
    var model = jtoken.ToObject<OutputStreamAMM>();
}
```

A simpler way would be to check for a key field that only one of the classes is known to have:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
if(token.SelectToken("$.average") != null)
{
    val model = token.ToObject<OutputStreamAMM>();
}
else
{
    val model = token.ToObject<OutputStream>();
}
```

Comment: So I need to build this schema for OutputStream and replace the ... with that right?

Comment: Correct. The method `JsonSchema.Parse` takes a string as an argument. I would advise storing the schema in its own file (`outputStreamSchema.json`), reading the file into memory (`File.ReadAllText`), and then passing its content into the parse method.

Comment: I've also added a simpler, more pragmatic way of doing this to my answer.

Comment: Oh, the method seems much more easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just inspect the json for some type of key identifier?

For example if the json contains "average" you have OutputStreamAMM. If not you have OutputStream.

Write a function that has that logic.